# PHP pull game scores for final games only

Tags: php

I have a php page that grabs pro football scores from the ESPN website, and then loads them in to a different page. It works great, but right now it loads scores for every game, even if the game is still in progress. I would like for it to only load scores for games that are final. Here is the code currently:

```
<?php

$week = (int)$_GET['week'];

//load source code, depending on the current week, of the website into a variable as a string
$url = "http://scores.espn.go.com/nfl/scoreboard?seasonYear=2014&seasonType=2&weekNumber=" . $week;

$raw = file_get_contents($url);

$teamCodes = array(
'GNB' => 'GB',
'JAC' => 'JAX',
'KAN' => 'KC',
'NWE' => 'NE',
'NOR' => 'NO',
'SDG' => 'SD',
'SFO' => 'SF',
'TAM' => 'TB'
);

$newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");
$content = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($raw));

$start = strpos($content,'<div class="gameDay-Container">');
$end = strpos($content,'<!-- begin sponsored links',$start) + 26;
$content = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);

//set search pattern (using regular expressions)
//$find = '|<div class="game-header">(.*?)<div class="game-links">|is';
$find = '|<p id=".*?-statusText">(.*?)</p>.*?<a href="/nfl/clubhouse\?team=(.*?)">(.*?)</a>.*?<li class="final" id=".*?-aTotal">(.*?)</li>.*?<a href="/nfl/clubhouse\?team=(.*?)">(.*?)</a>.*?<li class="final" id=".*?-hTotal">(.*?)</li>|is';
preg_match_all($find, $content, $matches);
//print_r($matches);
//exit;

//initiate scores array, to group teams and scores together in games
$scores = array();

//count number of teams found, to be used in the loop below
$count = count($matches[1]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
$overtime = (($matches[1][$i] == 'Final/OT') ? 1 : 0);
$away_team = strtoupper($matches[2][$i]);
$home_team = strtoupper($matches[5][$i]);
foreach ($teamCodes as $espnCode => $nflpCode) {
    if ($away_team == $espnCode) $away_team = $nflpCode;
    if ($home_team == $espnCode) $home_team = $nflpCode;
}
$away_score = (int)$matches[4][$i];
$home_score = (int)$matches[7][$i];

$winner = ($away_score > $home_score) ? $away_team : $home_team;
$gameID = getGameIDByTeamID($week, $home_team);
if (is_numeric(strip_tags($home_score)) && is_numeric(strip_tags($away_score))) {
if ($away_score > 0 || $home_score > 0) {
    $scores[] = array(
        'gameID' => $gameID,
        'awayteam' => $away_team,
        'visitorScore' => $away_score,
        'hometeam' => $home_team,
        'homeScore' => $home_score,
        'overtime' => $overtime,
        'winner' => $winner
    );
   }
   }
}

//see how the scores array looks
//echo '<pre>' . print_r($scores, true) . '</pre>';
echo json_encode($scores);

//game results and winning teams can now be accessed from the scores array
//e.g. $scores[0]['awayteam'] contains the name of the away team (['awayteam'] part) from the first game on the page ([0] part)
?>
```

Any idea how to modify this to grab the scores for final games only? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change the URL you grab to only show completed games?

Comment: Well, there isn't a URL that I know of that only shows final games...

Comment: It's a programming question, geez. I think I figured it out already, thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have figured it out. Will update tomorrow (Sunday, 9/7/14) to make sure (the only time to test is when games are in progress).

I changed this line, and prelim tests seem to work.

Change:

```
$find = '|<p id=".*?-statusText">(.*?)</p>
```

To this:

```
$find = '|<p id=".*?-statusText">(Final)</p>
```